# Display next first Sunday without specifying month in PHP

Tags: php, date, time

Our church website needs to display the date of the next "First Sunday of the Month" for our membership classes. For example this month we would like it to read "Join us for our next two week cycle starting June 7th". Then once that date passes it display the one for the next month. I have tried searching and using the answer given to similar questions and they either return errors or "01/01/70". Thanks!

Comment: `First Sunday of this Month`. Use `this` not `the`

Comment: Don't think that answers the question... nor the marked dupicate afaics.